# Android - LinerarLayout.AddView - why do i need to call setLayoutParams for inserted view?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

In runtime I am changing child of LinearLayout using addView method.

Just wondering if someone can explain me why I need to call setLayoutParams with MATCH_PARENT as both arguments on inserted view, when in layout root node for this view has layout_width and layout_height already set to match_parent?

Issue is only when inserted child is ConstraintLayout - with LinearLayout I don't need to call that method.

Main view:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <!-- left -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftPanel"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- center -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/centralPanel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="20"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5mm"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </LinearLayout>

<!-- right -->
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rightPanel"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1">
</RelativeLayout >
```

centralPanel is container that I am filling from code.

Item that is inserted:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <TextView
            style="@style/DescriptionTextView"
            android:id="@+id/mapTextView"
            android:text="@string/goToLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mapQuestImageView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            />

        <com.alexvasilkov.gestures.views.GestureImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapQuestImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mapTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mapQuestButton"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapQuestButton"
            style="@style/ContinueButtonStyle"
            android:onClick="simpleScreenNext"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mapQuestImageView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code before fix:

```
private void showCentralQuest() {
        LinearLayout centralPanel = findViewById(R.id.centralPanel);
        centralPanel.removeAllViews();
        
        centralPanel.addView(this.questLayout);
        centralPanel.invalidate();
    }
```

Fix (found here [Android: match_parent is ignored when using addView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201685/android-match-parent-is-ignored-when-using-addview) ) is just adding 1 line:

```
private void showCentralQuest() {
        LinearLayout centralPanel = findViewById(R.id.centralPanel);
        centralPanel.removeAllViews();
        
        this.questLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        centralPanel.addView(this.questLayout);
        centralPanel.invalidate();
    }
```

So anyone could explain it to me why I need to set LayoutParams again? :)

Comment: The `LayoutParams` on the root `<View>` in a layout will be created during inflation only if you pass the parent `ViewGroup` in the `LayoutInflater#inflate()` call. If you pass `null` for the parent, the `LayoutParams` are left null, because the particular type depends on the parent type; e.g., `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` for children inside a `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` inside a `FrameLayout`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. So calling `LayoutInflater#inflate()` is better/cleaner way to do what I am doing above?

Comment: I was assuming that that's how you're creating the item to insert, but I might have misunderstood. How are you creating `this.questLayout`? Is it from that second layout you've shown?

Comment: You are correct - it seems i forgot about that part of code. So probably initial problem is that i am calling `inflate` with wrong `root` argument. Will try to play with that part

Comment: Yeah, the second argument in `inflate()` is for the parent. If you don't want the newly inflated `View` to be added to the parent right away by `LayoutInflater`, you'll want to pass `false` for a third argument; e.g., `inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, centralParent, false)`. Just a heads up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.